# How to set a respawn system in cocos2d that is based on a timer?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I want to respawn enemy sprites based on a timer any suggestions would be appreciated.
Would be great if you show me some code examples.

```
   -(void)addEnemyAtX:(int)x y:(int)y {
  CCSprite *enemy = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"enemy1.png"];
  enemy.position = ccp(x, y);
  [self addChild:enemy];
  [self animateEnemy: enemy];}


  - (void) enemyMoveFinished:(id)sender {
CCSprite *enemy = (CCSprite *)sender;

    [self animateEnemy: enemy];
 }// a method to move the enemy 10 pixels toward the player
 - (void) animateEnemy:(CCSprite*)enemy
    {
    // speed of the enemy
     ccTime actualDuration = 0.3;

     // Create the actions
        id actionMove = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:actualDuration
                                                    position:ccpMult(ccpNormalize(ccpSub(player.position,enemy.position)), 10)];
     id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(enemyMoveFinished:)];
          [enemy runAction:
                 [CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];



         }
```

Comment: [self schedule:@selector(spawn:) interval:1.0f];
Everything else is too implementation-specific, you're not giving any details how you would like your sprites to be spawned (rules, conditions, etc).

Comment: I want it to spawn at the exact same spot as the enemy starts at. I want there to be up to unlimited amount of sprites and I want a new sprite to be made ever 15 seconds. I will post the enemy code.

Comment: That's a lot of sprites. Make sure to use a batch node and get rid of the ones you aren't using frequently or else you will have serious performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should learn the basics of Cocos2D first ;) It's pretty well covered in the book "Learning Cocos2D" - I recommend it! 
Nevertheless here is the line of code you want, I doubt though, that it is useful ;)

```
action = [CCSpawn actions:
          [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation
break;
restoreOriginalFrame:NO],
[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2.4f
 position:ccp([self position].x +
 nil];
xPositionOffSet,
[self position].y)],
```

Comment: How exactly do I implement it? And yes I am new, but I am trying to learn and I already learned a lot.

Comment: You should make an implementation file for the enemy. Like "MyEnemy.m" (and .h of course). There you can pretty much do everything you need the enemy to do. Also there goes the above code in the following method -> -(void)changeState:(CharacterStates)newState

Comment: I guess because you lack a few of methods ;) Like I said, try to get acquainted with the basics and it will come to you. It's not that hard, but far too much to explain here or even write all the code. I learnt it with the book "Learning Cocos2D" - Its really good. Otherwise you can just go to www.raywenderlich.com - There are a lot of tutorials, also some that talk about spawning enemies :)

Comment: which tutorial does he have respawning enemies?

Comment: Well don't be lazy and just go to the site ;) The first one for example covers who you can spawn multiple enemies which run across the screen http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial

Comment: I did do his tiled based tutorial, and try implementing the first tutorial spawning enemies. Pretty tricky

Comment: Don't worry you'll get the hang of it. It took me several days to learn various things about Cocos2D :) If you are satisfied with my answer, it would be nice of you to check it :)

Comment: I will never be satisfy :( but the problem I keep running into is it crashes when it respawns. Whats up with that!

Comment: Well, key is to learn, learn, learn. If you know why it crashes you are one step further in becoming a Cocos2D Developer.